# Is it possible to use multi threading while we use singleItemPeekableItemReader in Spring Batch to read a csv?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

Is it possible to use multi threading while we use `singleItemPeekableItemReader` in Spring batch to read a CSV?

I have a CSV file of 100 000 records and need to read that file using Spring Batch and load it into a database. I have used 4 threads for it. But now I have a requirement of combining rows based on a condition and read at a time. For this I have used `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` of Spring Batch. But after this I am unable to use multithreading.

How to implement multi threading for `SingleItemPeekableItemReader`?

Comment: What is the use case?

Answer (score 2):

File operations should not multi-threaded. Its recommended to use single thread alone. If you want performance then you can use batch operations. For faster CSV read operations you can use univocity CSV parser. Its very very fast and provides some useful methods as well.